# allow enter only 1 - 9 digits in textfield

Tags: ios

I need to allow the end user enter only 1-9 digits:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if([newString length]>=1)
        {
            NSString *sepStr=[newString substringToIndex:1];
            return !([sepStr length]>1);
        }

        if ([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0){
            textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            return NO;
        }
        NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
        if ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0)return YES;
        return NO;
    }
```

But it's still possible to enter more than 1 number.
Please help to find an error.

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit input to a 1-9 digits, as in "5" or "123456789" but not "1234567890", or one digit between 1 and 9, as in "1" or "5" but not "0" or "12"?

Comment: I mean allow only characters in the diapason {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
so for example 1 and not 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your first test :

```
if ([newString length] > 1)
    return NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you specify the numeric keyboard/keypad for this field with a max length of 1?

The UITextField object has a keyboardType property.  Set it to UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad

Comment: sorry for maybe dumb question, how can I do it?

Comment: textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;

Comment: ok, many thanks, now I have a proper keyboard, but I still can enter a decimal number. How can I solve it?

Comment: Then you have to make custom keyboard. Or else picker is the better option. You can show 1 to 9 and user will choose it.

Comment: yep, it's possible, but for me it seems that it's a case that had to be considered by the platform. :(

Comment: Setting the numeric keypad for this field won't prevent users with a Bluetooth keyboard typing letters.

Answer (score 1):

Cyrille has the correct answer, but just to let you know why it's not currently working:

When you enter the second digit, the code will go into this if statement:

```
if([newString length]>=1)
{
    NSString *sepStr=[newString substringToIndex:1];
    return !([sepStr length]>1);
}
```

which is always going to return YES, because sepStr is always going to have a length of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code it will work for me (Working Code)

#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"0123456789"

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([textField isEqual:zipCode]) {

```
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *number = @"[0-9]"; 
NSPredicate *numbertest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", number]; 
if ([numbertest evaluateWithObject:yourtextfield.text] != YES)
{
// Display error message
}
```

just use this code